# Parallel code throws OutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.0, out-of-memory, parallel-processing

Does anyone know how why this code returns out of range exception?
For example if the `leastAbstractions` List instance has `count == 10`, the loop will execute `11` times finishing with `i = 10` and returning this exception.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < leastAbstractions.Count; i++)
 {
     Task.Factory.StartNew((object state) =>
     {
         this.Authenticate(new HighFragment(leastAbstractions[i])).Reactivate();
     }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop isn't *actually* executing 11 times - it's only executing 10 times, but i == 10 by the time some of those tasks execute.

It's the normal problem - you're capturing a loop variable in a lambda expression. Just take a copy of the counter, and capture that instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < leastAbstractions.Count; i++)
 {
     int copy = i;
     Task.Factory.StartNew((object state) =>
     {
         this.Authenticate(new HighFragment(leastAbstractions[copy]))
                                     .Reactivate();
     }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
 }
```

That way, when your task executes, you'll see the current value of the "instance" of `copy` that you captured - and that value never changes, unlike the value of `i`.

See Eric Lippert's blog posts on this: [part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx); [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx).

Comment: I thought that the counter is passed as an argument immediately in the creation of the new task. I guess I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @blaze: You're using the counter *in the lambda expression*. When the lambda expression is executed, the *current* value of whatever you're capturing is used. That has to happen in a different thread, because that lambda expression is what your task is meant to do.